# DevExpress Populate AspxListBox with DataSet

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I have a DataSet that I retrieve from a database. I want to use that dataSet in order to populate a listbox, however I am having trouble following DevExpress documentation.

**Database Table (We do not need to know the phone and id data):** 
UserName | Phone | ID 
John
Yellow
Bob
Ron

Assume acctListDS is a dataset from a database table.

```
        AcctListBox.DataSource = acctListDS.Tables[0].DefaultView;

        AcctListBox.TextField = "UserName";
        AcctListBox.ValueField = "UserName";
        AcctListBox.DataBind();
```

Is this the correct way to set ValueField and TextField? I am not sure what they do or the information they take.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you contact DevExpress support directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These settings allow showing a value from the TextField, but store the real value from the ValueField (for example, when binding data via a foreign key, etc.). If you need to show and hold the same text values, your approach is quite correct.